# Chisel debug type inference

Tags: chisel

I'm getting an error during FIRRTL -> Verilog transformation.
I do the following in my code:

```
// Instantiate an Addr Translation Unit 
val atu = Module (new AddressTranslationUnit(vpnWidth.U, ppnWidth.U))
io.ptw(0) <> atu.io.out.bits.ptw
```

This passes initial compilation and I get a *.fir file. However, on the next step (verilog generation), FIRRTL performs more passes and my code fails with the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" firrtl.passes.CheckTypes$InvalidConnect:   
@[MyCore.scala 88:23:freechips.rocketchip.system.MYConfig.fir@147855.4]:
 [module GenericMY]  Type mismatch. Cannot connect atu.io.out.bits.ptw to io.ptw[0].
```

How to debug this?

I suspect that I get a width mismatch on a complex multicomponent bundle ( TLBPTWIO ), but I can only see in the *.fir output, which looks okay to me.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your question! Type mismatch means that the actual underlying types are different, not just the widths. Can you share a little more information? What are the types of `io.ptw(0)` and `atu.io.out.bits.ptw`?

Comment: @jkoenig Thank you for your answer. I was working on ROCC interface example when encountered this. The odd thing for me was that my code passed initial FIR elaboration and produced a *.fir output, but failed on verilog generation.

Comment: @jkoenig I could not debug that issue on my own, so I slightly rewrote the code and it has gone. I still don't understand Chisel and FIR on that level, but code refactoring did a trick. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Frequently when working with code using the Chisel2 compatibility wrapper (`import Chisel._`) as in rocket-chip, many errors are deferred to FIRRTL compilation. Even still in full Chisel3 (`import chisel3._`) some errors cannot be caught until FIRRTL. The issue you've pointed out here does illustrate that the FIRRTL error messages could use some improvement. I'll see what I can do.